# OrientDB: OPartitionedDatabasePool fails to re-open database connection after idling

Tags: orientdb

Using `OPartitionedDatabasePool` to acquire a connection and send a request with operation type `REQUEST_RECORD_CREATE` (31), i.e. insert a record, sometimes fails when the client fails to connect to the server.

When the connection has been idle for a while, the first insert fails with the message "The token provided is expired". Some auto-reconnect strategy then kicks in and the client sends operation type `REQUEST_DB_OPEN` (3). The server responds with a new token and starts writing out a lot of data to the client. After some back and forth, the client gets a successful response to `REQUEST_RECORD_CREATE`. All is well.

However, under some circumstances, the reconnect behaviour is never triggered. The client keeps sending `REQUEST_RECORD_CREATE`, and the server keeps responding "The token provided is expired", until the reconnect strategy reaches the retry limit and throws a `ODatabaseException`:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error during saving of record with rid #-1:-1
DB name="my_db"
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:197)
....
```

The circumstances under which this behaviour appears are still a bit unclear to me. So far I have only seen this on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM run on Hyper-V. Furthermore, it seems to happen only after the VM has been running for a couple of days, possibly subjected to some automatic Windows Update operation or such.

This is how the insert request is triggered from the client:

```
private final OPartitionedDatabasePool pool;

public JsonObject insert(String className, JsonObject recordData) {
    try (ODatabaseDocumentTx ignored = pool.acquire()) {
        ODocument document = new ODocument(className);
        document.fromJSON(recordData.encode());
        document.save();
        return new JsonObject(document.toJSON());
    }
}
```

Below is a log of a successful reconnect, somewhat truncated and modified for readability. The unsuccessful behaviour is exactly the same, except that the client never sends `REQUEST_DB_OPEN` (3), but just keeps sending `REQUEST_RECORD_CREATE` (31) until failure.

```
2017-05-17 02:00:01,571 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}}  null possible previous close - Closing socket...
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Connected
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing short (2 bytes): 36
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Read byte: 31
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Reading int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Read int: 3
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Read chunk lenght: 115
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Reading 115 bytes...
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Read 115 bytes:     my_db <truncated>
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OClientConnectionManager]  INFO: Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=6, source=/127.0.0.1:50249, since=1495006337692]
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing byte (1 byte): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing int (4 bytes): 3
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): []
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing byte (1 byte): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing string (4+78=82 bytes): com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OTokenSecurityException
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing string (4+29=33 bytes): The token provided is expired
2017-05-17 09:32:17,692 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:17,707 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50249 - Writing bytes (4+1508=1512 bytes): [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115 <truncated>
2017-05-17 09:32:17,707 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:17,707 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:17,818 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Closing socket...
2017-05-17 09:32:17,818 [OStorageRemote]  INFO: Caught Network I/O errors on 127.0.0.1:2424/my_db, trying an automatic reconnection... (error: null)
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Connected
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 36
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read byte: 3
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read int: -3
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OClientConnectionManager]  INFO: Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=7, source=/127.0.0.1:50250, since=1495006338319]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read string: OrientDB Java
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read string: 2.2.17
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading short (2 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read short: 36
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read string: ORecordSerializerBinary
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading boolean (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read boolean: true
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading boolean (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read boolean: true
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading boolean (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read boolean: true
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read string: my_db
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read string: writer
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read string: MVP00KNPxcWM3flpRpAGQG0O
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OClientConnectionManager]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=7, source=/127.0.0.1:50250, since=1495006338319]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing int (4 bytes): -3
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing int (4 bytes): 7
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing bytes (4+115=119 bytes): [0, 0, 0, 0,....]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 37
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+8=12 bytes): internal
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+5=9 bytes): index
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+8=12 bytes): manindex
....
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 16
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+5=9 bytes): event
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 17
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+7=11 bytes): event_1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 18
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+7=11 bytes): event_2
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 19
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+7=11 bytes): event_3
....
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 36
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): null
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+6=10 bytes): 2.2.17
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}}  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read byte: 31
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read int: 7
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read chunk lenght: 115
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading 115 bytes...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read 115 bytes:     my_db blablabla
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading short (2 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read short: -1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read chunk lenght: 75592
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading 75592 bytes...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read 75592 bytes:  bla bla bla
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read byte: 100
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,319 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read byte: 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing int (4 bytes): 7
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): []
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing short (2 bytes): 22
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing long (8 bytes): 8
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing int (4 bytes): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing int (4 bytes): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}}  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,350 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read byte: 41
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read int: 4
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read chunk lenght: 115
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Reading 115 bytes...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50250 - Read 115 bytes:     my_db  <truncated>
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OClientConnectionManager]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=8, source=/127.0.0.1:50250, since=1495006338366]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing byte (1 byte): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing int (4 bytes): 4
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): []
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing byte (1 byte): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+78=82 bytes): com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OTokenSecurityException
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing string (4+50=54 bytes): The token provided is expired
    DB name="my_db"
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50250 - Writing bytes (4+1518=1522 bytes): [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, ...]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,366 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,475 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Closing socket...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,475 [OStorageRemote]  INFO: Caught Network I/O errors on 127.0.0.1:2424/my_db, trying an automatic reconnection... (error: null)
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Connected
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 36
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO:  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read byte: 3
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read int: -4
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OClientConnectionManager]  INFO: Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=9, source=/127.0.0.1:50251, since=1495006338977]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read string: OrientDB Java
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read string: 2.2.17
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading short (2 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read short: 36
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read string: ORecordSerializerBinary
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading boolean (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read boolean: true
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading boolean (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read boolean: true
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading boolean (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read boolean: true
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read string: my_db
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read string: writer
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading string (4+N bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read string: MVP00KNPxcWM3flpRpAGQG0O
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OClientConnectionManager]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=9, source=/127.0.0.1:50251, since=1495006338977]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing int (4 bytes): -4
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing int (4 bytes): 9
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing bytes (4+115=119 bytes): [0, 0, 0, 0,...]
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 37
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+8=12 bytes): internal
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+5=9 bytes): index
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+8=12 bytes): manindex
...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 16
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+5=9 bytes): event
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 17
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+7=11 bytes): event_1
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 18
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+7=11 bytes): event_2
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 19
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+7=11 bytes): event_3
....
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing short (2 bytes): 36
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): null
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing string (4+6=10 bytes): 2.2.17
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}}  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read byte: 41
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read int: 9
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read chunk lenght: 115
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading 115 bytes...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read 115 bytes:     my_db ...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read byte: 97
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read chunk lenght: 151
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading 151 bytes...
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Read 151 bytes:    ;com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLAsynchQuery   'SELECT FROM my_table WHERE some_property = <...>       !  params    0   some_value
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing int (4 bytes): 9
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing bytes (4+0=4 bytes): []
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Writing byte (1 byte): 0
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}}  null possible previous close - Flush
2017-05-17 09:32:18,977 [OChannelBinaryServer]  INFO: $ANSI{green {db=my_db}} /127.0.0.1:50251 - Reading byte (1 byte)...
```

Comment: Which version of orientdb?

Comment: OrientDB version 2.2.17. I saw the same behaviour after updating to 2.2.19 though. Sorry for not being able to deliver more exact "how to reproduce" description, but I haven't really figured out that.

Comment: On 2.2.20 some issues were solved. Can you please test with it?

Comment: Absolutely. Since I'm not sure about the steps to reproduce it might be some time though. I'll get back here when I have something.

Comment: Small update on this: the problem remains on the 2.2.20. However, it is limited to a specific VM, so it must have something to do with how that VM is configured or managed. So probably not worth paying attention to, but out of curiosity I will keep trying to figure out what is going on here. The log says "token expired", could it be that the system time changes?